# IE css styling for border radius and background color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When both box shadow and background color exist for a link or button, IE shows a white line around it. Any idea what it is?

There is no other styling apart from what is used below. I checked in debugger tools of IE11 and chrome.
It does not happen with outline and background-color, just box-shadow and background-color.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/r3swzzLu/2/) (To be run on IE, I used IE 10)

[image]

```
//css
a,button {
  background-color: #61C250 !important;
  color: white !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 2px #61C250 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}


//html
<a href="#/random">Random Link</a>
<hr/>
<button>Random Button</button>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce in IE10 for Windows 8 or 10.

Comment: Mine is IE11 for windows 8. It should happen in IE10 too

Comment: I can reproduce it in IE11 in Windows 8.1; this is on a VirtualBox though.

Comment: I tried both virtual box and direct browser, happens in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IE shows a white line around it. Any idea what it is?

That appears to be a bug in IE, where its anti-alias effect for the elements edge picks up the color from the element behind it.

If you set the `body`'s background to red, the white line becomes red

```css
body { background: red; }
a,button {
  background-color: #61C250 !important;
  color: white !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 2px #61C250 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#/random">Random Link</a>
<hr/>
<button>Random Button</button>
```

Comment: I initally thought it could be because I am using border-color: transparent, but even if set border: 0px solid transparent/red/green it appears. Thanks for the info.